# how to override angular material mat-option style

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2, scss-lint, mat-option

[The height doesn't get bigger and the inscription gets smeared and not pretty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kj6m.png)
I have already tried many types of solutions but none of them worked I tried to do

```
::ng deep .mat-option{...}
```

But it didn't work
I tried to do

```
::ng-deep cdk-global-overlay-wrapper{
```

But that didn't work either
And I want to increase the height of
mat-option and it doesn't work

Comment: It is difficult to understand without more context. Please supply more relevant code (html, css).

Answer (score 1):

Assign a panel class for the mat-select, so that a custom class is available inside the overlay,

```
<mat-select panelClass="custom-select">
    <mat-option>option1</mat-option>
    <mat-option>option2</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

then in the main styles file styles.css add css rules in the custom class to override the default styles

```css
.mat-select-panel.custom-select .mat-option{
      height: 50px;
}
```